# mysql select query is very slow and uses filesort

Tags: mysql, performance, select

I have one big problem in the slow query select 
0.3054 sec

this the query

```
SELECT id, ar_name, en_name,product_id,havproduct, viewnum, uid,pin_to, sid, ssid,cid, close,date
FROM subject
where active = '1' and deleted = '0' and cid= '24'
order by id DESC
LIMIT 0,30
```

and when i use this

```
explain

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  subject     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    230026  Using where; Using filesort
```

and this table create

```
CREATE TABLE `subject` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `did` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ssid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `havproduct` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ar_name` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `en_name` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `close` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `viewnum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `pin_to` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `dep_active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and the table have 200000  record or more from data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no keys on your data.  For your particularly query, the best index is:

```
create index id_subject_4 on subject(active, deleted, cid, id)
```

By the way, you should only use single quotes for string and date constants.  All the values in your query are integers, so remove the quotes:

```
SELECT id, ar_name, en_name,product_id,havproduct, viewnum, uid, pin_to, sid, ssid,cid, close,date
FROM subject
where active = 1 and deleted = 0 and cid = 24
order by id DESC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```